# Find all php files which first or second line has more than N characters

Tags: regex, find, grep

I would like to find all php files on my server which first line or second line has more than N characters.

I would like to print both the file name and the line content that was found.

How would I do this? I am thinking on doing grep, but I don't know how to analyze lines on a file with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a way to do it:

```
MIN_WIDTH=30

for f in $(find / -iname  '*\.php'); do
  if [ $(head -n 2 "$f" | tail -n 1 | wc -c) -gt $MIN_WIDTH ] || [ $(head -n 1 "$f" | wc -c) -gt $MIN_WIDTH ]; then    
    echo "$f";
  fi
done
```

here's a breakdown:

- look up all `.php` files:   `find / -regex '.*\.php$'`
- get the second line of the file and count the number of characters: `head -2 "$f" | tail -1 | wc -c`
- get the first line of the file and count the number of chararcters: `head -1 "$f" | wc -c`
- compare whether each is greater than $MIN_WIDTH: `[ $(…) -gt $MIN_WIDTH ]
- if either of those is greater than `$MIN_WIDTH`: `if […] | […]`
- printout the name of the file: `echo "$f"`

Comment: It should be `$MIN_WIDTH` and you shoud add a `head -n 2 "$f"` after your `echo "$f"`. And quote all `$f` variables.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat shorter variant than zmo’s

```
find -iname "*.php" -exec grep -HP '.{6,}' {} \; | grep -P '^.+:[12]:'
```

where 6 is the minimum number of characters. The `-H` option is to print the filename even if only on file is grepped (this is the case, because every found file is grepped separately via the `{}` operator)